# jQuery problems chaining

Tags: jquery

I am trying to chain a function in jQuery and having problems.

http://jsfiddle.net/Aa7S9/7/

Basically, the syntax now is:

```
$("#newsletter").click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('html stuff')
.$("#transition").focus();
});
```

Any reason why this would be the case? I the replaceWith is working, and it returns a jQuery object and therefor should work with chaining.

(in actuality, I want to focus input in the JSFiddle to the input text box after it's injected into the DOM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need this
i have updated your js 
please check here
http://jsfiddle.net/Aa7S9/10/

```
$("#newsletter").click(function() {
$(this).replaceWith('<div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="pull-right form-       control input-lg" id="transition"><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>      </button></span></div>');
```

$('#transition').focus();
   });

Comment: yeah, this is what I ended up with as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`.alert()` is not a jquery method, you need to do:

```
$("#newsletter").click(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('html stuff');
    alert("this isn't firing");
});
```

---

You can just trigger `focus()` on the `input` element itself:

```
$("#newsletter").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var content = '<div class="input-group"><input type="text" class="pull-right form-control input-lg" id="transition"><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button></span></div>'
    $(this).replaceWith(content);
    $('#transition').focus();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aa7S9/8/)**

Comment: Your code is correct, but I updated my post as I was really attempting to use focus() to focus on a new text input that is created. I hope it's correctly shown in my example now.